# css width transition on hover over a link

Tags: html, css

i have a problem to use transition on a styled anchor.

it should expand to a higher width and show a glyphicon. i tried it width max-width but i think i miss something. the glyphicon works but not the "animated" width.

html:

```
<a class="link" href="/"> Order <a/>
```

css:

```
a.link {      
background: #0069b4 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
color: white;
font-size: 24px;
height: 60px;
cursor: pointer;
border-radius: 30px;
text-align: center;
padding: 10px 15px;
 transition: max-width 1000ms ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: max-width 1000ms ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: max-width 1000ms ease-in-out;    
}

a.link:hover {
    padding: 10px 40px;
    max-width: 100%;
}

a.link:hover:after {
    font-family: icomoon;
    content: "\e903";
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 20px;          
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lg7kutpp/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is not working, because it has no working width. It's changing size because of the padding, and therefore the transition:max-width will not work.

Easy way to fix with your code is to add transition:all.

Check this:

```css
a.link {      
background: #0069b4 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
color: white;
font-size: 24px;
height: 60px;
cursor: pointer;
border-radius: 30px;
text-align: center;
padding: 10px 15px;
 transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;    
}

a.link:hover {
    padding: 10px 40px;
    max-width: 100%;
}

a.link:hover:after {
    font-family: icomoon;
    content: "\e903";
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 20px;          
}
```

```html
<a class="link">Order></a>
```

I you just want to go with the transition only for the width property, you should add `display:inline-block` and a width property to the anchor class.

```css
a.link {      
background: #0069b4 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
color: white;
font-size: 24px;
height: 60px;
cursor: pointer;
border-radius: 30px;
width: 100px;  
 display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
padding: 10px 15px;
 transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: width 1s ease-in-out;    
}

a.link:hover {
    padding: 10px 40px;
    width: 150px;
}

a.link:hover:after {
    font-family: icomoon;
    content: "\e903";
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 20px;          
}
```

```html
<a class="link">Order</a>
```

Comment: Please mark it as solved if this works for you @Gabbax0r , glad it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
a.link {
  background: #0069b4 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  height: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 15px;

}

a.link:hover {
  padding: 10px 40px;
  max-width: 100%;
    transition: 1000ms ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition:1000ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:1000ms ease-in-out;
}

a.link:hover:after {
  font-family: icomoon;
  content: "\e903";
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;

}
```

You should add the transition on the hover selector without `max-width`

https://jsfiddle.net/Lg7kutpp/1/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to set max-width to something less than 100% in **a.link**.

What you're currently doing is setting max-width to 100% on hover, but the default setting of max-width is already 100%.

Either set max-width to something less than 100% under **a.link**, or set max-width to something greater than 100% under **a.link:hover**.

When it comes to the transition-property, you might as well write **transition: all 1000ms ease-in-out** rather than **transition: max-width 1000ms ease-in-out**, as using **all** will make sure that any animation on **a.link** will have the same properties.

Also, I'd recommend you don't use **href="/"** unless you intend to direct the user to the main page. If you just want an anchor that doesn't link anywhere, you can drop using **href**.

Hope this helps.